# Excel Count number of cells based on three dependent selects

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am looking to count the number of cells based on three dependent select statements. each select corresponds to a column.

For example,

```
Select nth-Day (Column A)
  Select Issue Type (Column B)
    Select Severity Level (Column C)

ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC 
Day1, Backend, Sev1 
Day1, Backend, Sev1
Day1, Frontend, Sev1 
Day1, Frontend, Sev2 
Day1, Frontend, Sev1 
Day2, Backend, Sev3 
Day2, Frontend, Sev3
```

So for
Day1, Backend, Sev1 = 2
Day1, Frontend, Sev1 = 2
Day2, Backend, Sev1 = 1

I can start with countifs but I'm stuck after that.

Any gurus?

Comment: What do you mean by 'select'?  Are these cells at the top of your sheet, with Data Validation limiting them to various values to provide a drop-down list?

Comment: I was trying to interpret the column selection using SQL nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
Countifs(A:A, "criteria for A", B:B, "criteria for B", C:C, "criteria for C")
```

in this case it would be

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Day1",B:B,"Backend",C:C,"Sev1")` = 2

Comment: What's the "= 2", mate?

Answer (score 0):

I would insert a Pivot Table based on the table of data (Insert ribbon).

I would add the Columns A - C as Row Labels or Column Labels or Filters.  I would drag any of the Fields to the Values zone to get a Count.